# How to implement a starwar energy shield in game

Tags: ogre

I am using Ogre3D.

How can I implement an energy shield like this [image](http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20090414152808/starwars/images/5/54/Energy_shield-1-.jpg)?

In the picture, the shield is a semi-sphere, where I want to make it a sphere surround my object. The shield should be transparent (this should be adjustable). Can the community advise how to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use:

- a semi-transparent sphere with a nice texture on it,
- a collision detection system to understand where the sphere has been hit,
- vertex and pixel shaders to implement ripples leaving from the contact point (maybe even with bump mapping, without actually displacing vertices).

Comment: And nice energy particle emitters at the point of contact that die out shortly after being spawned.

Answer (score 3):

The magic in that screenshot is the Fresnel effect at the border. A plain transparent sphere with a texture is not sufficient. There is a [demo](http://books.google.com/books?id=GifUrbWat14C&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=fresnel+example+ogre&source=bl&ots=gim2v3ppLj&sig=DWaAav4l9fBO0K6dO26-ORMecI4&hl=en&ei=JUPNTLbzGIb6sgbHuNGWCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) in the Ogre programming book, but I don't know if sources are available.

Answer (score 2):

For the "border" effect on the shield, you could try some Fresnel/Rim lighting shader.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't that just be a sphere with a partially transparent texture on it? You would need to break it into discrete polygons, but any 3D modeling package will have a drawing tool for this. The shimmer effect might be a little trickier, not sure how complex you are looking for though. Are you trying to do that kind of rippling impact animation too? The "right way" would probably be to implement it as a geometry shader, but that might be a lot harder than you need.

Comment: The shimmer effect can be just changing the shading on the original sphere. That's good for my current goal. Thanks.